# How to use source within a bash script to change the terminal prompt?

Tags: linux, bash, prompt, linux-terminal

I need to be able to use a script in ~/.local/bin/ (which is part of $PATH) to quickly change the prompt.

The desired result can achieved by running the following in a console:

```
 echo PS1='$\ ' > /tmp/ps1 && source /tmp/ps1 && rm /tmp/ps1
```

However, when put in a script, it will not affect the console in which it runs any more.

`. .local/bin/bigfont` works but writing the path to the script (or writing anything but the script name) should be avoided.

Is there a way to do this using a script? If not, is there a simple way to solve this using C?

Thanks!

Comment: First off, you don't need to write and source a file to change an environment variable--you can set PS1 just by executing `PS1='$\ '`. You could put `PS1='$\ '` in a script and source that. Alternatively, you could use a function instead of a script, which wouldn't need to be sourced but would be executed in the current environment so that you could set environment variables such as PS1. You can't do this in a script without sourcing it because the script runs as a child process of your shell and child processes cannot affect the environment of their parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a compromise, which will make it appear as if you are using a script.

Write a Bash function:

```
function miniprompt {
  PS1='$ '
  ~/.local/bin/somescript # or just somescript if it's in $PATH
}
```

To ensure that the function is always available, put it into `~/.bashrc` and `~/.bash_profile` (or just `~/.bashrc` if it gets loaded by `~/.bash_profile` anyway).

garyjohn made it clear that the question contains a wrong assumption that `source` must be used and clarified that one could instead set `PS1='$ '` directly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
function myprompt {
  export PS1=<set PS1 appropriately>
}

alias setprompt="PROMPT_COMMAND='myprompt'"
```

Running setprompt should set your prompt.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like...

```
export PS1="newprompt> "
exec bash
```

Which will work.. but it replaces your current bash shell with a new one and a fresh environment.